# Can I get valid screen coordinate with negative homogeneous w?

Tags: graphics, rendering, directx

Can I get valid screen coordinates with negative homogeneous w?

I'm making a software rasterizer.

When a vertex is outside of the view volume, homogeneous w is negative. This results in a weird screen space position, because dividing the clip space position by a negative w inverts the position.

I know that clipping solves this problem.
But I just want to know whether I can solve this problem without clipping.

Comment: Take a look at Olano&Greer (Triangle Scan Conversion using 2D Homogeneous Coordinates), Matthias Zwicker (Homogeneous Rasterization) and Blinn (Calculating Screen Coverage) papers.
I implemented a simple 3D engine that works well for triangles (lines are harder).

Answer (score 3):

A valid screen space position is characterized by the fact that

```
-w <= x,y,z <= w
```

Given that this may only hold when -w <= w, a negative w coordinate necessarily means that the point is outside of the visible area. But have a positive w is not a guarantee that the point is visible.

Note: When rendering anything else than simple points, you will have to implement a clipping algorithm. For example, a line might be visible even if both points are outside of the visible area.